# My Tomcat logs say I've successfully authenticated, but still get a 404. Does this rule out Tomcat as the cause?

Tags: authentication, tomcat, logging, jersey

I'm working on adding Form-based authentication to an existing Jersey webapp.  I was able to quickly get Basic authentication working successfully against my LDAP realm.  However, once I switched to Form and supplied a login/error page, the application does not present the page (gives a 404) after authentication.

When I setting up the web.xml with Basic Authentication I got the  username/password dropdown (supplied by the web browser), signed in, and the Jersey app presented all the pages like it did before any authentication was set up.

After switching to Form, I monitored my tomcat logs during a login and can see it appears to be authenticating successfully.

```
01-May-2019 16:09:26.603 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasRole Username [me@awesome.com] has role [app-user]
01-May-2019 16:09:26.603 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasResourcePermission Role found:  app-user
01-May-2019 16:09:26.604 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Successfully passed all security constraints
```

I would suspect I can rule out my tomcat security setup being the problem, since the logs indicate I'm authenticating successfully.  My assumption is that there is something different about Basic and Form authentication where the Jersey webapp I was given needs to change.

Given the logs, should I focus my attention on the Jersey application?

Comment: What happens during the form login? Is the client given some kind of token, is there a cookie added? How is that authentication being persisted?

Comment: I'm actually not sure -- thanks for asking the question.  I do not do anything with tokens, cookies, or persisting of authentication besides only what tomcat would automatically do.  

I could be misunderstanding what is expected of me when configuring the tomcat to use form authentication.  My understanding was that if Basic Authentication worked, then Form is the same except for I define what the Login page looks like.

Comment: Error 404 means NOT FOUND, might occur regardless of authentication. May be a redirect after login is providing the wrong URL. You can check that with dev tools in browser with persistent logs enabled.

Comment: Thanks Luis, the interesting thing about the Not Found message is that the application / tomcat serves up the same pages perfectly fine (No 404) when using simple basic auth.  Could the application need cookie handling or something in order to work with Form authentication?